# Cookie not geting saved on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timezone, timezone-offset

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var newMinutes = d.getTimezoneOffset();

    var storedMinutes = getCookieValue("tzom");

    if (newMinutes != storedMinutes) {
        setCookie("tzom", newMinutes);

        alert("new" + newMinutes);
        alert("stored" + storedMinutes);

        document.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do here is check a timezone value in a cookie to see if it is different to the current timezone set by the user.  This will happen if I user comes to the site and changes their timezone and then goes to another page.  If there is a difference then I set the cookie with the new value and reload the page.  The problem is that when I reload the page it still shows that there is a difference in the timezones and so the page reloads in an infinite loop.  If I am somehow able to click on a different page during this infinite loop then the looping stops.

In fact, what I have noticed, by taking out the reload, is that after changing my timezone, if I click on a page the timezone is reported to be different, if I then click on a second page the timezone still is reported to be different and it is only on the third page click that there is no reporting of the cookies being different.

What is wrong here?

**EDIT**

Rest of the code is here

```
function getCookieValue(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setCookie function takes 3 parameters, not 2.

Try changing your code into this:

```
if (newMinutes != storedMinutes) {
    setCookie("tzom", newMinutes,365); //cookie will persist for 365 days

    alert("new" + newMinutes);
    alert("stored" + storedMinutes);

    setTimeout("document.location.reload(true)",1000);
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with it.  The last parameter is allowed to be null, which is handled in the method if you look closely.  But to rule things out, I will try it.

Comment: The last parameter can be null... But if it's null, then the cookie is set to expire immediately...

Comment: I see, how can I set it to infinite.

Comment: All cookies expire... What you can do is set the expiration to a far away date... (5+ years for instance)

Comment: does the page still refresh on a endless loop?

Comment: Yes it does keep looping.

Comment: I've updated the code to wait one sec, before trying to reload the page... Can you check if that fixes the problem?